# Clickatell REST API giving error

Tags: clickatell

Hi I am using clickatell REST api and getting following error:

```
{"messages":[],"error":"ScheduledDeliveryTime format is incorrect. - "}"
```

I am using correct format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"

please help to fix this issue.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to do exactly like in documentation

--> 2018-01-25T18:17:20+0200

+0200 is your timezone

And don't forget to concatenate 'T' letter in the middle

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to schedule it for a later time, remove that property(name-value pair) from your json.

That worked for me for now but please do post the real answer if you found it.

Comment: I could not found the answer, I just removed that property and worked for me. The Message was sent and logged in Clickatell dashboard but never received on my mobile due to the network issue, I have sent a support request to Clickatell but hey are too slow to reply back!